# trigger.io: autocomplete textbox is not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, trigger.io

I need an autocomplete textbox in my Iphone/Android App.

I have tried JQuery and native HTML5 autocomplete textboxes but it nothing seems to work both JSON requests nor datalists.

Im testing on an Android device Samsung Galaxy s2

```
<label>
  Enter your favorite cartoon character:<br />
  <input type="text" name="favCharacter" list="characters" maxlength="50" style="width:95%;">
  <datalist id="characters">
   <option value="Homer Simpson">
   <option value="Bart">
   <option value="Fred Flinstone">
  </datalist>
 </label>
```

Anyone faced this issue before ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datalist feature is not supported by Android webkit, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist

You should be able to use a jQuery plugin to achieve a similar effect though, have you tried http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/